# CSS positioning in responsive grid system

Tags: html, css, grid, system, responsive

I am learning how to make responsive websites. I downloaded Responsive Grid System and I am learning responsiveness with this system (you'll see what I have In `html` on screenshot).

Now I have some troubles with `positioning`. I use `media queries`. For mobile view from `320px` to `480px` I have no problem, but then when I want to make `logo` centered in range `480px` to `768px` I have problem with `col span_6_of_12` (you'll see that also on the screenshot). I have `logo` in one `col span_6_of_12` and then I have menu in second `col span_6_of_12`. When I want to make `logo` centered, this menu `col span_6_of_12` is still there and I can't make this `logo` centered (I hope you understand me.)

[HTML and Chrome view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr2R9.png)
- Here is screenshot of my HTML and Chrome view on site.

And here is CSS code:

```
html {
background-color: #FFF;
}
body {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
width: 100%;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding: 0;
margin: 10px 0;
}
nav li {
display: block;
padding: 10px;
}
#menu {
display: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
#logo {
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu {
    display: none;
}
nav ul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {
#menu {
    display: none;
}
#logo {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

}
```

Comment: You should set either `(max-width: 479px)` or `(min-width: 481px)` in media queries. And you don't need to define `#menu { display: none; }` in media queries while you set it within default rules.

Comment: I changed that now, but nothing happens. I have #menu {display: none} bcs I have slicknav menu and I want to hide my original menu. I want just this dropdown menu on mobiles and tablets. On larger screen I will hide this dropdown menu and I will use original menu what I created.